# Tapping a badge achievement in app loads site in browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

In the achievements inbox, if I tap a badge achievement, I get taken to the relevant site in the in-app browser, rather than being shown the site natively, in the app.

Apologies I can work out how to word that better - essentially I get the below screen within the app, which isn't very helpful!

[image]

Comment: What badge did you get? Generally when you tap a badge it takes you to the post that earned it.

Comment: This was the "curious" badge - so it's really only specific to the site, rather than a particular post. Incidentaly, the badge takes me to this link on the site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/233816/chris?tab=badges (But I don't think that could be replicated in the app so well!)

Comment: @Brian - To clarify - it's a metaSE badge - it doesn't take me to that link for all badges!

Comment: We could probably add a screen around [this API call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-on-users#order=desc&sort=awarded&ids=233816&filter=!--DMfKJLmhin&site=meta&run=true)  The only thing the API really lacks is specific dates and posts around a specific badge award.

Comment: @Brian. Fair enough. Is the extra work really necessary though? I'm not fussed about being able to see my badges, just think it should lead somewhere more sensible than it currently does!

Comment: Even better: on iPad, it loads the homepage [in a tiny box](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PFQhS.jpg).

Comment: @abby - Aww. Ain't that cute. =)

Comment: I've gone with a slightly-better-than-what-we-have-now solution.

Comment: Thanks @Brain - at least this move will be a bit less weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem we're facing is twofold:

1. The link in question is for `http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=badges`.  Since we don't have a native view of the page, we load the page in a web view.
2. Because we don't (yet) exchange auth information with the app, meta.SE doesn't have a current user and it redirects you to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/` and you get the question list.

There's really nothing good we can do here aside from (a) implementing every web page that could come from a badge or (b) implementing authorization of the SE site through the app.  I'd like to do (b) but there's no timetable for that right now so I'm going to do the next best thing of sending you to Safari and hoping you're logged in there.

You should see this in the next build.