# Automatically log me in to the mobile website when coming from the app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login, ios-app, mobile-web

When now clicking on a link to the website inside the iOS app, you aren't logged in.

It seems a nice feature to me when clicking on a link that refers to one of the SE sites, you are automatically logged in and don't need to enter your credentials again. (I am logged on in Safari, but that doesn't seem to come through in the apps browser window)

> [image: logon screen inside the app]

(Note that I am not talking about logging into Safari (the browser app). I am talking about the browser windows *inside* the SE app).

Comment: Not sure how this is possible, Stack Exchange app doesn't really have such control over other apps on your device. (e.g. Chrome, Safari)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am talking about the browser inside the app, it doesn't seem to take cookies from Safari, so maybe they can make it working inside the app only.

Comment: The ideas been [mentioned before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248351/233816). Sounds like it's planned, but not *planned*!

Comment: @Chris Thanks. Now we have something to monitor the status :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has pretty much fixed itself. In iOS 9 we are now using the Safari view controller to show web pages, so if you are logged in in Safari things should just work.

Comment: Does this mean it logs you in to chat if you follow a chat link, too? Or is that different because chat windows pop open in the actual Safari app?

Comment: @Catija We don't log you in, but we're hoping you should already be logged in and if not you should have a much easier time logging in because it's the real browser.